# SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Tno', table 'dbTaskManager.dbo.tblTask'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, exception

I have a following exception in my code. I already read many solutions but never worked in my case. Table `tblTask` contains columns `taskId` and `Tno`. `taskId` is set to be an identity column, and I pass a specific value for `Tno`, but I get this exception:

> SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Tno', table 'dbTaskManager.dbo.tblTask'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Here is the table design

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblTask] (
[TaskId]             NUMERIC (18)    IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[ClientId]           INT             NULL,
[UserName]           VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
[Task]               VARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
[EmpId]              INT             NULL,
[AssignedDate]       DATETIME2 (7)   NULL,
[DueDate]            DATETIME2 (7)   NULL,
[CompletionDate]     DATETIME2 (7)   NULL,
[EstTime]            FLOAT (53)      NULL,
[ActualTime]         VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
[Status]             VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
[Priority]           VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
[Remarks]            VARCHAR (8000)  NULL,
[TechnicalRemarks1]  VARCHAR (8000)  NULL,
[TechnicalRemarks2]  VARCHAR (8000)  NULL,
[TechnicalRemarks3]  VARCHAR (8000)  NULL,
[TaskPercentage]     NUMERIC (18, 2) NULL,
[StartTime]          DATETIME2 (7)   NULL,
[Tno]                INT             NOT NULL,
[DeliverToday]       BIT             NULL,
[dt_Status]          BIT             NULL,
[UpdateStatusNO]     INT             CONSTRAINT [DF__tblTask__UpdateS__5070F446] DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
[patchStatus]        INT             NULL,
[SupportFile]        VARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
[Codecommit]         INT             NULL,
[Tremark1file]       VARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
[Tremark2file]       VARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
[remarkfile]         VARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
[Taskfile]           VARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
[Moduleid]           INT             NULL,
[StatusDate]         DATETIME2 (7)   NULL,
[ParentID]           INT             NULL,
[TaskTypeid]         INT             NULL,
[Projectid]          INT             NULL,
[SubTaskTypeid]      INT             NULL,
[Ptaskid]            INT             NULL,
[DepartmentID]       INT             NULL,
[SuggesionRemarks]   VARCHAR (8000)  NULL,
[DevHours]           FLOAT (53)      NULL,
[Start]              INT             NULL,
[IsStartDate]        INT             NULL,
[ReleaseID]          NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
[Bug]                INT             NULL,
[Suggestions]        INT             NULL,
[Approved]           INT             NULL,
[Movement]           INT             NULL,
[QAHrs]              NUMERIC (18)    NULL,
[MiscHrs]            NUMERIC (18)    NULL,
[summary]            VARCHAR (500)   NULL,
[Email]              VARCHAR (500)   NULL,
[LocalClientDetails] VARCHAR (500)   NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_tblTask] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Tno] ASC)
);


GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateTblTask]  ON  dbo.tblTask
for Update
AS 
BEGIN

if Update(Status) or Update(EmpID)
begin
    insert into tblTaskLog (TaskId,ClientId,UserName,Task,EmpIdFrom,EmpIdTo,AssignedDate,DueDate,EstTime,StatusFrom,StatusTo,SystemName,CreationDate)
    select  D.TaskId,D.ClientId,D.UserName,D.Task,D.EmpId,I.EmpId,D.AssignedDate,D.DueDate,D.EstTime,D.Status,i.Status,Host_Name(),Getdate()
    From Deleted D inner join Inserted I on D.TaskId=I.TaskId
    Where D.Status<>I.Status or D.EmpID<>I.EmpID
    ------------------------------------------------------

    ---------------------Status Change---------------------
    if Update(Status)
    begin
         Declare @OldStatus  varchar(200)
         Declare @NewStatus  varchar(200)
        select @NewStatus=Status  from inserted
        select @OldStatus=Status from deleted
        --select @NewStatus NewStatus,@OldStatus OldStatus
        --if((Select status from inserted)<>(select Status from deleted))
        if @NewStatus <> @OldStatus
        begin

            Update tbltask set Statusdate=Getdate() where taskid=(Select Taskid from inserted)
        end

    end
    --------------------------------------------------------------

End

End
GO
DISABLE TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateTblTask]
    ON [dbo].[tblTask];
```

Here is TaskMainDTO.cs

```
[Table("tblTask")]
public class TaskMainDTO
{
    public int? ClientId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Task { get; set; }
    public int? EmpId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AssignedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CompletionDate { get; set; }
    public double? EstTime { get; set; }
    public string ActualTime { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    public string TechnicalRemarks1 { get; set; }
    public string TechnicalRemarks2 { get; set; }
    public string TechnicalRemarks3 { get; set; }
    public decimal? TaskPercentage { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int Tno { get; set; }
    public bool? DeliverToday { get; set; }
    public bool? dt_Status { get; set; }
    public int? UpdateStatusNo { get; set; }
    public int? patchStatus { get; set; }
    public string SupportFile { get; set; }
    public int? Codecommit { get; set; }
    public string Tremark1file { get; set; }
    public string Tremark2file { get; set; }
    public string remarkfile { get; set; }
    public string Taskfile { get; set; }
    public int? Moduleid { get; set; }
    public DateTime StatusDate { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public int? TaskTypeid { get; set; }
    public int? Projectid { get; set; }
    public int? SubTaskTypeid { get; set; }
    public int? Ptaskid { get; set; }
    public int? DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string SuggesionRemarks { get; set; }
    public double? DevHours { get; set; }
    public int? Start { get; set; }
    public int? IsStartDate { get; set; }
    public string ReleaseID { get; set; }
    public int? Bug { get; set; }
    public int? Suggestions { get; set; }
    public int? Approved { get; set; }
    public int? Movement { get; set; }
    public decimal? QAHrs { get; set; }
    public decimal? MiscHrs { get; set; }
    public string summary { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string LocalClientDetails { get; set; }
```

Here is TaskMainVM.cs

```
 public class TaskMainVM
{
    public TaskMainVM()
    {

    }
    public TaskMainVM(TaskMainDTO model)
    {
        ClientId = model.ClientId;
        Projectid = model.Projectid;
        Moduleid = model.Moduleid;
        TaskTypeid = model.TaskTypeid;
        SubTaskTypeid = model.SubTaskTypeid;
        EmpId = model.EmpId;
        DepartmentID = model.DepartmentID;
        Username = model.Username;
        Status = model.Status;
        Priority = model.Priority;
        ReleaseID = model.ReleaseID;
        AssignedDate = model.AssignedDate;
        DueDate = model.DueDate;
        CompletionDate = model.CompletionDate;
        StartTime = model.StartTime;
        ActualTime = model.ActualTime;
        DevHours = model.DevHours;
        QAHrs = model.QAHrs;
        MiscHrs = model.MiscHrs;
        Tno = model.Tno;
        summary = model.summary;
        Task = model.Task;
        Taskfile = model.Taskfile;
        LocalClientDetails = model.LocalClientDetails;
        Email = model.Email;

    }

    public int? ClientId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Task { get; set; }
    public int? EmpId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AssignedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CompletionDate { get; set; }
    public double? EstTime { get; set; }
    public string ActualTime { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    public string TechnicalRemarks1 { get; set; }
    public string TechnicalRemarks2 { get; set; }
    public string TechnicalRemarks3 { get; set; }
    public decimal? TaskPercentage { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }

    public int Tno { get; set; }
    public bool? DeliverToday { get; set; }
    public bool? dt_Status { get; set; }
    public int? UpdateStatusNo { get; set; }
    public int? patchStatus { get; set; }
    public string SupportFile { get; set; }
    public int? Codecommit { get; set; }
    public string Tremark1file { get; set; }
    public string Tremark2file { get; set; }
    public string remarkfile { get; set; }
    public string Taskfile { get; set; }
    public int? Moduleid { get; set; }
    public DateTime StatusDate { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public int? TaskTypeid { get; set; }
    public int? Projectid { get; set; }
    public int? SubTaskTypeid { get; set; }
    public int? Ptaskid { get; set; }
    public int? DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string SuggesionRemarks { get; set; }
    public double? DevHours { get; set; }
    public int? Start { get; set; }
    public int? IsStartDate { get; set; }
    public string ReleaseID { get; set; }
    public int? Bug { get; set; }
    public int? Suggestions { get; set; }
    public int? Approved { get; set; }
    public int? Movement { get; set; }
    public decimal? QAHrs { get; set; }
    public decimal? MiscHrs { get; set; }
    public string summary { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string LocalClientDetails { get; set; }
```

Here is TaskController.cs

```
 // save task data
    public JsonResult SaveTaskDataInDb(TaskMainVM model)
    {
        var result = false;
        try
        {
            using (Db db = new Db())
            {
                    TaskMainDTO dto = new TaskMainDTO();

                dto.ClientId = model.ClientId;
                dto.Projectid = model.Projectid;
                dto.Moduleid = model.Moduleid;
                dto.TaskTypeid = model.TaskTypeid;
                dto.SubTaskTypeid = model.SubTaskTypeid;
                dto.EmpId = model.EmpId;
                dto.DepartmentID = model.DepartmentID;
                dto.Username = model.Username;
                dto.Status = model.Status;
                dto.Priority = model.Priority;
                dto.ReleaseID = model.ReleaseID;
                dto.AssignedDate = model.AssignedDate;
                dto.DueDate = model.DueDate;
                dto.CompletionDate = model.CompletionDate;
                dto.StartTime = model.StartTime;
                dto.ActualTime = model.ActualTime;
                dto.DevHours = model.DevHours;
                dto.QAHrs = model.QAHrs;
                dto.MiscHrs = model.MiscHrs;
                dto.Tno = 78999;
                dto.summary = model.summary;
                dto.Task = model.Task;
                dto.Taskfile = model.Taskfile;
                dto.LocalClientDetails = model.LocalClientDetails;
                dto.Email = model.Email;


                db.TaskMain.Add(dto);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    result = true;


            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Comment: So for one of the columns you are not setting a value so it passes it NULL which is not allowed. Can you post the table script used to create it and the code you are using to add the data to this table?

Comment: Your insert query does not set a value for `Tno` but the table is designed to require a value.

Comment: **SHOW US THE CODE!** we cannot possibly read your screen, nor your mind - you have to **show us** what you're doing, then we *might* be able to help !

Comment: @HenryMigo  kindly see now ...i add all the code.

Comment: @marc_s  kindly see now ...i add all the code.

Comment: @Crowcoder Thanks for your response but i already set value to Tno...kindly see my code now

Comment: The error does not lie, you can be sure the database is receiving a null. Step through your code in the debugger, it should be pretty straightforward to see what the values are just before running the query.

Answer (score 0):

Your table has the following NOT NULL columns `TaskId`, `Tno`, `ReleaseID`.

As you are making an insertion operation, then you have not to check a column `TaskID` as this column has `IDENTITY(1,1,)`. This means that SQL Server will care about this column by itself.

However, the rest two NOT NULL columns such as `Tno`, `ReleaseID` should be cared by you. So just use null coalescing operator `??` to set a fallback value to these columns if they are assigned null values:

```
using (Db db = new Db())
{
     TaskMainDTO dto = new TaskMainDTO();
     //...
     dto.ReleaseID = model.ReleaseID ?? 0;
     //...
     dto.Tno = 78999;
}
```

UPDATE:

This row means that if `model.ReleaseID` does not have any value(it means `NULL`), then `dto.ReleaseID` will be set to `0`. The `0` here is fallback value to prevent of getting exception `SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL ...`:

```
dto.ReleaseID = model.ReleaseID ?? 0;
```

If you do not want to set `0`, then you can throw an exception:

```
if(model.ReleaseID == null || dto.Tno == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("SaveTaskDataInDb(TaskMainVM model) method 
        received a null argument!");
```

Comment: @SetUp ..thanks for your response.....i can't understand what actually u say ...can u explain it little bit more ?

Comment: @AaqibAliBhutta What he is saying is if a NULL ReleaseID is passed the '??' operator will use '0' instead thus not handing the SQL a NULL value. Do be aware that if you do want ReleaseID to always have a value using the '??' is not a good idea, as you want it to fail when a null is passed. If not it would be better to make the releaseID nullable in the table.

Comment: @HenryMigo for your response

Comment: @SetUp ...thanks your response....it is good practice approach.....i re-bulit insertion method using sp and it is working now ...